# Is it possible to run a task after the watch task?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have a PHP-based project that won't run on [grunt-php](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-php). Instead, I use [grunt-exec](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec) to run my MAMP server for development.

```
exec: {
  serverup: {
    command: '/Applications/MAMP/bin/start.sh'
  },
  serverdown: {
    command: '/Applications/MAMP/bin/stop.sh'
  }
}
```

In my custom development task, I run the MAMP start script just before my watch task. Then, I'm trying to stop the MAMP server after I've exited the watch task.

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'concat', 'compass:dev', 'exec:serverup', 'watch', 'exec:serverdown']);
```

However, if I exit the task with Ctrl-C, the `exec:serverdown` task never seems to run. Is there any way to make this work? Since the server never goes down, that port is tied up until I manually run the stop script, and I get errors if I try to run the default task again before bringing it down.

If not, is there some other way I could accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Do you mind sharing why it won't work with grunt-php?

Comment: @SindreSorhus I don't know exactly. I'm developing a theme for [Koken](http://koken.me/). I started out trying to use grunt-php, but I couldn't get the install to complete. I posted on the Koken forums and was told by a dev it wouldn't work with the built-in PHP server which is apparently what grunt-php uses. He didn't say why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could listen on `SIGINT` and run the script:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    exec('/Applications/MAMP/bin/stop.sh', function () {
        process.exit();
    });
});

module.exports = function (grunt) {};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Looks promising. I will try it out soon and report back.

Comment: I'm having some trouble with this. I'm not sure exactly where this should go in my Gruntfile. If I include it inside `module.exports = function (grunt) {...}`, I can no longer end the task with Ctrl-C. If I put it outside that function, I get `Fatal error: grunt is not defined`.

Comment: That allows me to exit the task, but the server is still up when all is said and done. I can run `grunt exec:serverdown` manually, and the server does go down.

Comment: Seems like grunt.task.run is async without having a callback, which makes it run process.exit() before being able to run the task. I've updated the answer with another solution.