# How to run a task after grunt watch finishes?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Is there an option to run a particular task after each watch run?
e.g.

```
watch : {
  js: {files:[], tasks:[]},
  css: {files:[], tasks:[]},
}
```

I want to run task "foo" after both `watch:js` and `watch:css`, and I don't want to add that task to each and every watch multitasks tasks list, and I don't want to add a new watch task with all files from other tasks to be watched.

Is there a watch general `options.afterEach` api or something?

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @SkipJack, thanks for your answer, but i wanted something more clean that could be later maintained and used by other team members. i would probably have to add setTimeout to the event callback to postpone the execution to after other tasks. and i'm no so sure what happens in combination with grunt-concurrent.

Comment: No problem, yea I actually don't use Grunt anymore (moved to Webpack) but I was surprised that there wasn't a more maintainable option for this as it seems like a somewhat common use case. I think your best bet might be to subscribe to that github issue and see what others are suggesting there.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**: No

There isn't a built-in way with Grunt or Grunt Watch. [This github issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/542) discusses the possibility of adding in the next version.

There is a `watch` event but nothing like `watch:start` or `watch:end` as far as I know. You can use the this event like so:

```
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath, target) {
    grunt.log.writeln('Here is the action : ' + action);
    grunt.log.writeln('Here is the filepath : ' + filepath);
});
```

Unfortunately this only runs at the beginning:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Here is the action : changed
Here is the filepath : pre/js/console.js
>> File "pre/js/console.js" changed.
Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
...
```

**Related Questions:**

[Is it possible to run a task after the watch task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710568/is-it-possible-to-run-a-task-after-the-watch-task)

[Run a command after a grunt task finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182581/run-a-command-after-a-grunt-task-finishes)